# How to select attributes that do not appear in the group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables with 1:n relation

```
Product (id1, id2, name, CreatedBy)
ProductVersion (id, ProductId1, ProductId2,VersionNumber, description)
```

( 
  * Each package has more than one version (numbered sequentially
  * Package has id1 and id2 that makes together the unique key
)

I query the latest (top) version for each product as follows

```
SELECT p.id1, p.id2, max(pv.VersionNumber)
FROM Product p 
join ProductVersion pv on p.Id1 = pv.ProductId1 and p.Id2 = pv.ProductId2
group by p.Id1, p.id2
```

Now,
I want the pv.id - the id of the version which was returned as top.
How do I fetch it?

Comment: I assume `PackageId` was supposed to be `ProductId`

Comment: wouldn't you sort the statement then select top 1?

Comment: Fixed and added the double columns in my key - as in my real problem

Comment: I really wish you'd stop changing your requirements. I keep having to re-write my answer! I'm stepping out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, for example:

```
select p.id1, p.id2, pv.id
from Product as p
    outer apply (
        select top 1 t.id
        from ProductVersion as t
        where t.ProductId1 = p.Id1 and t.ProductId2 = p.Id2
        order by t.VersionNumber desc
    ) as pv
```

or use row_number() approach:

```
with cte as (
    select
        p.id1, p.id2, pv.id,
        row_number() over(partition by p.id1, p.id2 order by pv.VersionNumber desc) as rn
    from Product as p
        left outer join ProductVersion as pv on pv.ProductId1 = p.Id1 and pv.ProductId2 = p.Id2
)
select * from cte where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can further refine your join to join only on the max version number:

```
SELECT   p.id
       , pv.id AS VersionId
       , pv.VersionNumber
FROM     Product p 
JOIN     ProductVersion pv
     ON  p.Id = pv.ProductId
     AND pv.VersionNumber = (  SELECT MAX(VersionNumber)
                               FROM ProductVersion
                               WHERE ProductId = p.Id)
```